# Pohlig–Hellman/Big step baby step

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, cryptography, discrete-logarithms

I had an original question $g^x≡h\pmod p$ where $g=5$ $h=1000$ $p=1000777$ solving for $x$

I calculated $N=p-1=2^3\cdot3\cdot7^2\cdot23\cdot37=1000776$

calculating $g1,...,g5$ and $h1,...,h5$

$g1=5^{1000776/8}$  $h1=1000^{1000776/8}$

$g2=5^{1000776/3}$  $h2=1000^{1000776/3}$

$g3=5^{1000776/49}$   $h3=1000^{1000776/49}$

and so on for $i=4,5$

equating them for g1 raising it to the xI have

$$(5^{125097})^x= 1000^{125097} \bmod 1000776$$

My question is how would I solve this using baby step/giant step algorithms or any other way. Thank you.

Comment: yes thats correct I guess its the same as calculating in my case $ 5^{125097} mod(1000776)$ and $1000^{125097}mod(1000776)$

Comment: I know that is the answer but I want to calculate it manually

Comment: Oh my apologise but that would be amazing